# `ctest` and `GTEST_REPEAT`

Tags: testing, googletest, ctest

I'm using CMake (and ctest) 3.11 with Google Test.

Is there any way to benefit from `GTEST_SHUFFLE` and `GTEST_REPEAT` while using ctest?  ctest runs one unit test per process, so shuffling the tests is pretty much pointless currently. Am I missing anything?

Thanks